# Prooving not all roots are real

Tags: inequality, polynomials, roots

Let $P(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\dots+a_0$

Given $a_{n-1}^2<a_{n-2},$  prove not all roots can be real

My attempt:
Assume all roots are real, namely $R_1,R_2,\dots,R_n$

Then $-a_{n-1}=\sum_{i=1}^n R_i$
$a_{n-2}=\sum R_i\times R_j$

Now $$(R_1+R_2+\dots+R_n)^2<(R_1R_2+R_1R_3\dots R_{n-1}R_{n})\\
\implies R_1^2+R_2^2\dots R_n^2<-(R_1R_2+R_1R_3\dots R_{n-1}R_{n})$$

But we can't tell if RHS is actually negative or positive. Also this kinda looks like cauchy-schwarz. Can it be used here?

Comment: Where did you get this formula from please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**  From $\displaystyle (\sum_i R_i)^2 < \sum_{i< j} R_i R_j$, we may add $\frac12 \sum R_i^2$ to both sides to get
$$\left(\sum_i R_i \right)^2 + \frac12\sum_i R_i^2 < \frac12 \left(\sum_i R_i \right)^2 $$
$$\implies \frac12\left(\sum_i R_i \right)^2  + \frac12\sum_i R_i^2 < 0$$

which is absurd.

Comment: The OP formula is not true for $x^2+x+1$! It also does not work for $x^3+25x-3x^2-75$ which has roots $5i, -5i, 3$.

Comment: @NoChance Your first e.g. does not satisfy $a_{n-1}^2<a_{n-2}$ and is hence irrelevant.  The second e.g. satisfies the given condition, and does not have all real roots, so illustrates in this case the OP's condition works.  Not sure how you conclude the OP is incorrect, in fact there is a proof of it given above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My confusion comes from the statement "not all roots can be real". Upon re-examining it I conclude that (A) Either all roots are complex and/or (B) There are some real roots and some complex roots. In both cases, there must be complex roots. Following this thought, I can understand the OP proposition. I guess this is correct.